# limiting distribution of an exponential function

Tags: limits, distribution-theory

Question: Find the limit of the function $f(x) = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+}\frac{e^\frac{-x^2}{\epsilon}}{\sqrt \epsilon}$ in the distribution sense:

My Attempt : $\left< f_\epsilon,\phi \right> = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^\frac{-x^2}{\epsilon}}{\sqrt \epsilon}\phi(x) dx= -2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{xe^\frac{-x^2}{\epsilon}}{\epsilon^\frac{3}{2}}\phi(x) dx$

I was planning to use the change of variable technique. But stucked.
Could you please solve this problem for me ?

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+}\frac{e^\frac{-x^2}{\epsilon}}{\sqrt \epsilon}
= \sqrt{\pi} \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+}\frac{e^\frac{-x^2}{2 \epsilon}}{\sqrt{ 2\pi \epsilon}}
$$

Limit of standard normal distribution is Dirac function at zero. Hence the limit above is $\sqrt{\pi} \delta(x).$

Comment: It's not clear to me. Would you please write some more steps to make it clear?

Comment: Substitute $2\epsilon$ instead of $\epsilon$ in the first limit and then multiply and divide by $\sqrt{\pi}$. Note that the expression after the second limit above is the density of a normal distribution with mean zero and variance $\epsilon^2$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
\langle f_\epsilon, \phi \rangle 
&= \epsilon^{-1/2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2/\epsilon} \, \phi(x) \, dx \\
&= \{ \xi = \epsilon^{-1/2} x \} \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\xi^2} \, \phi(\epsilon^{1/2} \xi) \, d\xi \\
&\to \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\xi^2} \, \phi(0) \, d\xi \\
&= \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\xi^2} \, d\xi \right) \phi(0) \\
&= \{ \text{Gaussian integral} \} \\
&= \sqrt{\pi} \, \phi(0) \\
&= \langle \sqrt{\pi} \, \delta, \phi \rangle
\end{align}$$

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) about the Gaussian integral.

Comment: wow, That's really nice, What's about this problem: $f (x) = lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{\epsilon}{x^2 + \epsilon^2}$

Comment: @TazimTaz. Set $x = \epsilon \xi$. The calculations will be similar to the above, and you will get the integral 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\xi^2+1} d\xi = \pi.$$

Comment: Thank you @md2perpe  I got the answer $2\pi \phi(0)$

Comment: @TazimTaz. From where did you get the factor $2$?

Comment: Sorry Typo, I got $\pi \phi(0)$

Comment: Would you please do me a favor? I wrote a proof of Theorem : Let $u \in D'(R) $ and $u'=0$, Prove that u = constant. I am hoping someone to check my proof.

Comment: @TazimTaz. Sure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92397/discussion-between-tazim-taz-and-md2perpe).